# PHP 5.2.18 coming out?

Tags: php

Does anyone think or know whether PHP 5.2.18 is coming out? I want to finalize my installation with the last 5.2.x and don't want to go through it again. I won't be switching to 5.3 for a long time. Too many sites and deprecated features to go through.

Comment: You can just turn off deprecated warnings. From what I know, no features have actually been removed between 5.2 and 5.3

Comment: @Jacob You know wrong: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php

Comment: and http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php
i will miss eregi()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP 5.2 is considered as not maintained anymore.

So, in theory, there should be no new version of PHP 5.2 -- and no new version is planned.

See the [announcement of PHP 5.2.16](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1) :

> This release marks the **end of support
>   for PHP 5.2**. 
> All users of PHP 5.2
>   are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.3.

Still, **if** a very severe / critical bug is detected, it is **possible** that some PHP code-developper **might** decide to release a new version, to fix that bug.

That's what caused the release of [**PHP 5.2.17**](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-01-06-1), for instance.

But this is not something that's supposed to happen ever again : critical bugs are not something you expect ;-)

Comment: yes 5.2.17 was unexpected. so thats why i was wonder if any more changes are being pushed as 5.2.18 or there is no activity.

Comment: As you say, 5.2.17 was unexpected ;-) If there is ever going to be a 5.2.18, it is currently not expected *(maybe it might happen, if there is a really important reason ; but that reason, as of today, doesn't exist)*

Comment: 5.2.18 will be like the Spanish Inquisition - unexpected.

Comment: Nobody unexpects the Spanish Inquisition? Doesn't have quite the same ring to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable deprecated messages in your "php.ini" config file. Its not the best way but so you can use php 5.3 and work step by step on the notices.

Comment: some are completely disabled http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Comment: ok what is disabled? ;) deprecated means, that in the next php version this functions is removed. All my old 5.2 apps runs under 5.3. But when you update to PHP 6 you have problems. @Mike

Comment: are you sure? I think eregi() is completely disabled in 5.3 isnt it? or will it still work but keep warning me?

Comment: you are right. i was under the impression is was already removed!

Comment: No you can use it but in the next version its removed. ;) @Mike